# How to upload file using ajax file upload and spring mvc?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a jsp file in which i am uploading a file using ajax file upload method. For backend handling of file i made a contoller in spring. But i could not find that how can i handle file in spring 2.5 in this condition ?
My Code is -

**JSP FILE**

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
<script type="text/javascript">
        function saveMedia() {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
            console.log("form data " + formData);
            $.ajax({
                url : 'ajaxSaveMedia.do',
                data : formData,
                processData : false,
                contentType : false,
                type : 'POST',
                success : function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error : function(err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two main steps:

1) add an instance of [multipart resolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartResolver.html) to the Spring context

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

2) add a handler method

```
// I assume that your controller is annotated with /ajaxSaveMedia.do
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String doUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) {                 
    return "Uploaded: " + multipartFile.getSize() + " bytes";
}
```

---

To get an instance of `java.io.File` from [`org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html):

```
File file = new File("my-file.txt");
multipartFile.transferTo(file);
```

Comment: ok but i want to do it without annotations ... How can i do that ?

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991519/spring-mvc-3-1-without-annotations) for configuration without annotations. You have to use `request.getInputStream()` in this case. However, I would recommend annotation configuration.